# how to send form value with "onClick="window.location.href "

Tags: javascript, php, html

i need to stay on the same page so i'm not using submit button. How can i go to php page and send form values?
exempel:

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label> <input type="file" name="csv" id="csv"/>
 <input type= "button" value="immport" onClick = "window.location.href =readFile.php'
 .(this.form);" > 
 </form>
```

this doesn't work. other options?

Comment: try using ajax call: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: You may want to learn separation of concerns first. Inline JS is bad practice to do

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: i would prefer not to use ajax or jQuery

Comment: You're a bit knackered then!

Comment: Then you're SOL, because forms are default synchronous.

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery. You don't even need a `form` if using AJAX, unless you use `buttonElement.onclick = function(){formElement.submit();}`. If you use the example I showed, the page might scroll or flash when in reloads. I would use AJAX. Note: You should keep your JavaScript separate from your HTML, and get into the practice of not camel casing Event listeners like `onClick`. It should be `onclick`. I would just keep all of your HTML lowercase with the exception of `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: You do know that you can use a `submit` button and stay on the same page, right? Of course, the page will appear to reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use an AJAX call **(?... see comments)**, There is a classic way to submit your form, but this results in reloading the actual page:

The form is in the same script as the logic is. In your case, that would be `readFile.php`.

Use the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` as form action:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label> <input type="file" name="csv" id="csv"/>
    <input type= "submit" value="immport" /> 
</form>
```

The form will be submitted to the actual page. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> `$_SERVER` is an array containing information such as headers, paths,
>   and script locations.
>
> ...
>
> `'PHP_SELF'` The filename of the currently executing script, relative to
>   the document root....

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code Will Work For You:

```
 <form action="readFile.php" name="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label> <input type="file" name="csv" id="csv"/>
 <input type="button" value="immport" onClick = "document.myform.submit();" > 
 </form>
```

Or You can use this javascript function to submit a form without submit button:

```
<form action="readFile.php" name="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label> <input type="file" name="csv" id="csv"/>
<input type="button" value="immport" onClick = "submitform();" > 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
 if(document.myform.submit())
 {//this check triggers the validations
    document.myform.submit();
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is actually quite easy with HTML5.  Check out W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

With HTML5, the BUTTON tag has the option to specify a "formtarget".  Again, W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formtarget.asp

This allows you to tell the form to submit to a different target window.  From there, you would add to your submission page an instruction to close upon submission, that way the user should only see a flash of the window that is opening.

Your submission button could look like this:

```
<button type="submit" formtarget="submission">Submit</button>
```

While you submission page could include a simple JavaScript like:

```
window.close();
```

I hope this helps. ^^

Comment: I agree, but sritno was clear about not using AJAX or jQuery.

Comment: That would open the response in a new page. It wouldn't run PHP from a page other than what the `<form action=`.

Comment: From the description given, sritno wants the form to submit without leaving the form page.  He doesn't give any specifics other than no AJAX or jQuery.  This method submits the form to a new window, allowing the data to be processed without ever leaving the original form page.  I've used formtarget before, and it works, but I usually have additional code, like jQuery, to do something else on the form page window.

Comment: That wouldn't really be the staying on the same page principle, now would it?

Comment: Yes, and no.  The form page never changes.  With a code, like the JavaScript "window.close()" I provided, to close the submission window after processing, assuming the server or client aren't stupid slow, that target window closes and all that is left is the original form window.